# Find the general rule for the pattern 0, 2, -2, 0, 2, -2, 0, 2, -2

Tags: sequences-and-series

This pattern is not an arithmetic sequence or a geometric sequence. How would you find the general rule?

Answer (score 2):

If you start from $x_0$, try $x_n = -2+2 ((n+1) \bmod 3)$.

If you start from $x_1$, try $x_n = -2+2 (n \bmod 3)$.

Comment: I like this method. I was thinking of using trigonometry, which would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you start counting from $1$, the rule seems to be $$f(n)=\begin {cases} 0&n\equiv 1 \pmod 3\\2&n \equiv 2 \pmod 3\\-2&n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \end {cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

This sequence is twice http://oeis.org/A102283, which includes several formulas.

Roman Witula gives a trigonometric one, which here becomes

$$a(n)=\dfrac{4\sin\left(\dfrac{2 \pi n}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

starting with $n=0$.